# "Isolator polynomials" don't work with complex roots?

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have just implemented the algorithm explained at https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.133.2233&rep=rep1&type=pdf to isolate the real roots of a quintic polynomial. My algorithm works perfectly when my polynomial has all real roots, but when it has two complex roots, for example, it is failing.

My input polynomial is:
$$p(x) = x^5 -0.375x^3 - 0.1625x^2 -2.7x - 1$$
which has the real roots:
$$x_0 = -1.224$$
$$x_1 = -0.374$$
$$x_2 = 1.449$$
which means that (according to the example isolator polynomial formulae for quintics in the paper at the bottom of page 3) my isolator polynomials and their roots are:
$$a(x) = -39.94453125x^2 + 7.3921875x + 10.66875, (x_0 = 0.61756, x_1 = -0.4325)$$
$$b(x) = -3.75x^2 + 2.4375x + 0.5625, (x_0 = 0.8306, x_1 = -0.1806)$$

The idea of the isolator polynomials, as the paper explains, is that the roots of these "IPs" can be used as the interval bounds to isolate the roots of the original polynomial.

I have graphed these equations using Desmos (link: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bwkm7yx7pt), and it is clear that the two quadratics do not isolate the roots (at least, the two right roots of the quadratics don't - it appears that the two left roots still contain the middle root of the quintic, however I'm not sure if that is a coincedence or not.)

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Is there a flaw or my calculation? Or perhaps the algorithm? My goal is to isolate at least two real roots so that I can solve them using Newton's method, deflate the quintic to a cubic, and then solve using the cubic formula.

Help would be much appreciated!

Edit: After checking my calculations again, I cannot find an arithmetic error

Comment: If you’re looking for ways to numerically find multiple (all) roots at once then there are [other ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms#Finding_all_roots_at_once) to do that.

Comment: @WimC thank you, but (from what I can tell) a lot of those methods are general purpose in the sense that they cater for degrees of 100+ etc. Since my polynomial is always going to be a quintic, if I can get this algorithm to work, it definitely appears more efficient from a computational perspective (no construction of sturm sequences, closed-form "plug-and-play" formula, etc.) I will use those methods if needs be, but this one is my preferred one for now

Comment: The paper says that the set of combined roots of $a$ and $b$ contains at least one element in each interval, which is the case in your example.

Comment: Does that not mean that each set must contain one element, i.e. the roots 0.618 and 0.831 should contain one root between them as well?

Comment: Aberth is very fast and very simple to implement and basically works to find any number of roots simultaneously.

Comment: @WimC thanks, I will give it a try if I don't resolve this issue

Comment: It’s the other way around: between each pair of adjacent roots of the quintic there is at least one root of either $a$ or $b$.

Comment: I understand now... eish. So the algorithm is (effectively) useless if your quintic has any complex roots? It would only guarantee that (if we worked backwards) the interval formed by the smallest and largest roots of a(x) and b(x) would contain (at least) one root of p(x)? So you effectively haven't isolated any roots at all?

Comment: Depending on your definition of “useless”.  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your comment on my post on SO. I am using IPs for solving quintics, and for your example I seem to get the appropriate real roots.

> roots.rkt> (roots-quint 1.0 0.0 -0.375 -0.1625 -2.7 -1.0)
>
> '(-1.22423523014232 -0.3742386961297533 1.4494051911699204)`

(From Mathematica: x == -1.22424 || x == -0.374239 || x == 0.0745344 - 1.22489 I ||
x == 0.0745344 + 1.22489 I || x == 1.44941)

My isolator polynomial roots are (sorted):
-0.43249415130797386 -0.1805937104039171 0.6175554668040721 0.8305937104039172

So your IP roots seems right, of course that's evident from the plot. These roots *separate* real roots of the original quintic if any. So if there are roots in any of the following intervals, there must exactly be one root.

1. [-∞, -0.43249] `-1.22423523014232`
2. [-0.43249, -0.18059] `-0.3742386961297533`
3. [-0.18059, 0.61756]
4. [0.61756, 0.83059]
5. [0.83059, +∞] `1.4494051911699204`

This is just like your plot shows.

Note that I used Lagrange's root bounds instead of +∞. and `-1 * upper-bound of P(-x)` instead -∞. Then used https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228712261_Bisected_Direct_Quadratic_Regula_Falsi. My Scheme/Racket implementation of Brent's is slightly slower.

5 roots cannot be bounded with 3 intervals, which is what 4 roots of the isolator polynomial can give you. But the do isolate the roots like the name says. You would need an upper and lower bound for the real roots of the original poly along with the isolator polynomial roots. There are several bounds available for you to pick. Since my strategy is to only use Brent's or BDQRF to find and deflate the left-most root, then solve the quartic, I didn't think it was worth to find a tighter upper/lower root bound.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: btw. Lagrange's bound for this poly was -2.6432, much more manageable than -∞